# fscanf a number and store each digit in an array

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I have a file with a number like "100000". Is there a way to store each digit in an array? For example, I make an `array[100]` and I want `array[0] = 1`, `array[1] = 0`, `array[2] = 0` and etc. I've looked it up but from what I gather, if I use a char array it takes it as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

I probably would not use `fscanf()` for this:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isdigit(c))
    array[i++] = c - '0';
```

If you must use `fscanf()`, then:

```
int i = 0;
int v;
while (fscanf(fp, "%1d", &v) == 1)
{
    assert(v >= 0 && v <= 9);
    array[i++] = v;
}
```

The 1 in the format string limits the integer to one digit.  You must pass in an `int *` if you use `%1d`.  If you have C99 support in your library, you could use:

```
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%1hhd", &array[i++]) == 1)
    ;
```

The `hh` length modifier indicates that the pointer is a pointer to char (very short integer) rather than a pointer to `int`.

Comment: In the first example, why do you substract `'0'` ?

Comment: @Amit: because the character code for `'0'` is typically 48 (but that is _not_ guaranteed), and the character code for `'9'` is typically 57, so to convert from the character code for a digit to the number corresponding to the digit, you subtract `'0'`.  This works for every codeset (EBCDIC, ISO/IEC 8859-x, Unicode, etc).  It only runs into problems if there are other types of digits, such as the Hindi digits (Unicode U+0660 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO, etc).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused. You're storing a character that you read into the char variable `c`, correct? So you read the digit `1`, store it as a character into `c`, and then store `c - 0` into the integer array. Would you substract `0` for any `integer` that is read. For example, what if the file had `14122`. Would this approach still work?

Comment: @Amit: `printf("%c %d\n", '0', '0');` will most likely print `0 48`. So, reading one character into a variable `c`, if the character is `'0'` (note the single quotes), the value stored is (probably) 48. To convert that to 0 (note the absence of quotes), we can subtract `'0'`; the same subtraction from `'1'` will yield 1, and from `'2'` will yield 2, etc. So, each digit read will be converted into a number. When treated as a character, 0 could be regarded as control-@, and 1 as control-A, and 2 as control-B, etc, or 0 as NUL, 1 as SOH, 2 as STX, etc. Note that `'0' != 0`; that is crucial.

Comment: +1 @Jonathan Leffler: I understand now, thanks a lot, that clarifies things. Still a C noob :/

Answer (score 0):

Is the number stored as literal '100000', or as its binary representation? if it's the literal '100000', just read it into a string, which is a char array already.

Answer (score 0):

As you use fscanf to read input into a char array, you can iterate over that array and apply atoi to each element and put the output (an integer) into your int array.